# Passing Google Places Results into ListView

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, hashmap

I am developing an application that displays taxi companies around you. The home page is a Map with markers showing the different cab companies. Is there a way to get the details such as Name, Address and Phone Number to a `ListView` on the next page? Is it possible to pass the `HashMap` details to the `ListView` and if so, how? Can it be added to this class below that shows the map markers?

```
package com.example.chela.taxilocatorapplication;


import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.util.List;

public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
        com.example.chela.taxilocatorapplication.Places placeJsonParser = new com.example.chela.taxilocatorapplication.Places();

        try {
            mMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
            googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
            googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        mMap.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            jsongetcart = new ParseGetCartFromOrderList();
            jsongetcart.quantity = j
            jsongetcart.currency =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("currency")
            cartListFromOrder.add(jsongetcart);

        }
```

do like this here is cartListFromOrder is my arraylist and i am addin currency in it you can add name,phone no any think and ParseGetCartFromOrderList() is my model class

```
   public class ParseGetCartFromOrderList {
    public String locid;

    public String currency;}
```

and use this class as datatype in your array list like this

`public static ArrayList<ParseGetCartFromOrderList> cartListFromOrder;`

now you can easily add this data to adapter using setter and getter`